# Implicitly generated initializer list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

In C++ standard for `std::array` it says:

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the
>   syntax
>
> array a = { initializer-list };
>
> where initializer-list is
>   a comma-separated list of up to N elements whose types are convertible
>   to T.

Also it says that `std::array` is an aggregate type and its constructors are implicitly generated.

To initialize an `std::array` with an initializer list it must have a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list` as an argument.

Is a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list` also implicitly generated for user-defined types or it is specific to `std::array`?

Comment: I think you're confusing *initializer-list* and `std::initializer_ist`. One is a grammatical term, the other is a type. You have misquoted the typography of the standard!

Comment: The type of an initializer-list is `std::initializer_list`. There should be a constructor taking `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: "The type of an initializer-list is std::initializer_list" No it is not, as Kerrek just explained. In this context, initializer-list simply is "a comma-separated list of up to N elements whose types are convertible to T".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

The syntax works for aggregate types,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int get_a() {return a;}
};

int main() {
    A a1({4,5});
    A a2{1,2};
    cout << a1.a << '\n';
    cout << a2.b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/qBOL8i)

But technically for aggregate types there is no constructor created. Those invocations present two forms of [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Since `T` is an aggregate, it falls for the [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) related bullet.

Answer (score 6):

No, the compiler does **not** generate a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`, neither for `std::array` nor for any other aggregate type.

What you observe here is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) which is completely unrelated to `std::initializer_list`.

The term "initializer-list" in the standard snippet you provided refers to a list of initializers, which again has nothing to do with `std::initializer_list`.

You can test that with something like this:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    std::string str;
};

int main() {
    A a{1, "asdf"};
}
```

This works, but clearly does not make use of `std::initializer_list` since that can only handle a *single* type at once.

Answer (score 1):

`std::array` is aggregate and so aggregate-initialization is used, and no constructor that receives `std::initializer_list` is generated.

> If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the
>   object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>
> List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a
>   *braced-init-list*. Such an initializer is called an *initializer list*,
>   and the comma-separated *initializer-clauses* of the list are called the
>   *elements* of the initializer list.
>
> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as
>   follows:
>
> If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
>
> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified
>   in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding *initializer-clause*.